# How to stop a video to keep downloading after html node is removed?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

My website is a single page app.
Protocol used => h3

**PROBLEM**:

Videos keep being downloaded even after I remove the parent nodes.

---

**SITUATION**:

I have many videos in a page. The videos autoplay with an `intersectionObserver` when appearing on screen.

Some videos have started downloading from the server.

Then, I go to another page.

All the parent's nodes are removed.

New nodes are created with none containing video html tag.

However, videos keep downloading in background, using bandwidth and requests.

New requests are blocked, therefore blocking rendering.

---

**WHAT I TRIED**

1.Pausing all videos before removing nodes:

```
document.querySelectorAll("video").forEach( element => {
    element.pause();
    element.querySelector("source").src = "";

});
```

Not stopping downloads.

2.Stopping all the requests before removing nodes:

```
window.stop()
```

This solution is not ok because I may have some pending async requests that I want to be fulfilled.

Answer (score 0):

Just simplily set video dom element src to "" before removing it. And it will prevent background downloading.

Comment: Already tried, see `element.querySelector("source").src = "";`in my question

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).